# Getting "Uncaught Error: undefinedModule" when using "require('fs')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm requesting using `const fs = require('fs');` in by code, but when I try to run it I always get this error: **Uncaught Error: undefinedModule** at the exact line where I've put the `require`. 
I'm currently using Eclipse to write my code and I've installed node.js and also fs.js, but that doesn't seem to matter. 
 I don't know how I can fix this problem and I really need this module.

Comment: why you need fs.js? fs is built-in with node

Comment: I was searching to resolve this and for lack of knowledge (I'm new to node.js) I think I thought that they were the same, I've installed fs.js after I got this problem while trying to fix it